# How to easily start a webserver in any folder?

Tags: webserver

I'm looking for a relatively painless way to launch a web server with document root in any folder I specify (or better yet, where I'm launching).

I often try out new things like JS frameworks or so in a new folder somewhere here:

```
/home/alexander/code/angularjs/
```

It would then be convenient to just go into this directory and type something like:

```
start-webserver-here
```

so that a web server starts listening on port 80 and serving this directory, and I can try out whatever I'm working on.

I've installed XAMPP but it seems that it's basic apache with a document root I'd have to change, with root privileges even, along with granting permissions for every folder etc.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Someone has compiled a big list of one liners to achieve this:
https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Use

```
python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

or

```
python3 -m http.server 80
```

to start a simple HTTP server.

Replace `80` with  another number if you want it to listen on a different port. For ports < 1024 it needs to run with root privileges.

Comment: Can you run this in parallel to Apache? On a different port of course (Though I would welcome you to blow my mind by telling me they can use the same ports).

Comment: @dibs Yes they can both run in parallel. But no, not on the same port.

Comment: The python SimpleHTTPServer is awesome - but do remember that this can only serve "static" files, not execute PHP/Python/"backend" requests. But it is really handy in a cinch for your use case!

Comment: The python 3.x equivalent of this is `python3 -m http.server`

Comment: thats why i love stackoverflow so much .Came looking here for the exact problem I wanted to find a soultion for ... run angularjs from a webserver. Thanks much Florian Deisch

Comment: Does this allow downloading from anywhere in Internet?

Comment: Can you change it to use HTTP version 1.1?

Comment: Does work, but unfortunately it does not support range-get so does not work well when I tried to serve a video to my smart-tv since seeking does not work. VLC somehow manages to fake seeking, I guess it just brute-forces it and downloads the whole video up to the seek point ;) I ended up using the node `http-server` answer which worked great https://askubuntu.com/a/1052250/196546

Answer (score 33):

I also like to use PHP for this purpose, as it enables me to run stuff like WordPress on the fly and develop themes more easily (you still need MySQL, though):

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In the [same script](https://github.com/kermit666/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/kermit-app-server) that starts this I also start [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload), which auto-refreshes the browser on file change.

Comment: Note that the built-in server feature was [added in 5.4.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Yes, you need one of the newer version. The version in the 13.10 repos if you do `sudo apt-get install php5` is 5.5.3, so you should be OK.

Comment: Perfect ! Just what I was looking for !

Answer (score 19):

if you are more ruby minded, the [serve](http://rubygems.org/gems/serve) gem is great

```
serve
```

or for i different port:

```
serve 9000
```

install with `gem install serve`

Comment: This works fine, but it requires ruby >= 1.9.3

Comment: Yep, but also [1.9.3 is eol](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/02/23/support-for-ruby-1-9-3-has-ended/). Security patches are no longer backported.

Would recommend [rvm](https://rvm.io/) for managing legacy rubies. They should not be your system's default

Answer (score 17):

This is also possible in Ruby without installing a gem.

`ruby -run -e httpd . -p5000`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Which version of ruby did you try ?

Comment: Works as advertised with Ruby 2.5.1.

Comment: Only answer on this page that supports byte-range requests!

Comment: Thanks. Never used Ruby in my life, but this worked as-is.  Mine seems to be 2.5.1.

Comment: @neopostmodern [the gem way](https://askubuntu.com/a/377469/21005) supports byte-range requests as well.

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu (and probably almost all other Linux distos) you already have [BusyBox](https://www.busybox.net/) installed. If not then on Ubuntu you may install `sudo apt install busybox-static`. So you can run [httpd](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#httpd):

```
busybox httpd -f -vv -p 8080
```

then open http://localhost:8080

In sources [httpd.c](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c) you may find more details.
It is very limited but have almost all basic functionality like Basic Auth, cache validation by ETag, serving pre-compressed gzip files, and CGI scripts.

BTW the BusyBox is also widely used in embedded devices: WiFi routers, TV boxes etc.

But OpenWrt, which is open source firmware for WiFi routers, use own http server: [uhttpd](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/uhttpd). It's inspired by bb-httpd and has more features like built-in Lua interpreter. And you can compile and install it on any other Linux.

Yes, it's not built-in into Ubuntu and not so easy to install but this may be useful if you still want a small footprint web server but bb-httpd doesn't fit your needs.

For Ubuntu I created a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Estokito/+archive/ubuntu/openwrt) which contains the uhttpd.

Comment: note that this does not include directory index listing. that you need to add yourself as a cgi-bin script

Comment: Yes and BusyBod has index cgi program but you have to compile it yourself https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd_indexcgi.c

Comment: BTW there is more cgi scripts for directory listing https://github.com/HeGanjie/busybox-httpd-directory-listing

Answer (score 10):

Just use `http-server`, it's a zero-configuration command line server.

The easiest way to install it is through npm:

```
sudo npm install http-server -g
```

Usage:

```
http-server [path] [options]
```

`[path]` defaults to `./public` if the folder exists, and `./` otherwise.

To see your server in action visit http://localhost:8080. Use `-p` option to set a different port.

For more options visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server.

Comment: The only reason not to use this is that it requires rpm that is not natively installed. The other solutions that mention ruby and python are pre-installed on almost every OS, so there is not a pre-requisite associated with installing the command to run the server.

Comment: @jamescampbell I suppose you meant _npm_. Ruby is not pre-installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: Worked well to serve video to my smart TV. `http-server` seems to support range-get, so seeking in the video worked. Agree with @jamescampbell, main disadvantage is having to install extra things since npm is not part of the default install.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Nginx for that: https://gist.github.com/asterite3/89236d1753a669e173531aca4b87afdc

This is not single-threaded (server won't hang for other clients if accessed from, say, google-chrome) and is very configurable and effective.

Comment: I get some permission denied errors with nginx. Does it require running as superuser?

Comment: No, it should not require  running as superuser. If you get an error `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)` then it's OK - Nginx will indeed try to open "/var/log/nginx/error.log" and fail, but it should proceed and launch  normally. Error log won't be lost (it will be written to `stderr` due to `error_log /dev/stderr;`). Or do you get a different error? (if yes, what is it?)

Answer (score 2):

Since there's angularjs in your folder's name, it seems like it's an angular js app. In such case, be sure to check [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) out.

To quote it's site

> Yeoman 1.0 is more than just a tool. It's a workflow; a collection of tools and best practices working in harmony to make developing for the web even better.

One of many other things is the bundled `grunt` server.

Answer (score 0):

You want JS Lightning. It is just what the doctor ordered. It's a Node JS app.

Install it. Type "js-lightning" in any directory with servile files and it will serve on port 7000. Give it another port and you're good there instead. Lots of good features to make it useful.

For good measure, it will serve anything in the directory that it can "require()". Which is to say, it serves .js files in a manner inspired by PHP.

http://jsLightning.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ran](https://github.com/m3ng9i/ran) a cross-platform language-agnostic, static http server