# Ubuntu 16.04 apt-get update doesn't work with local repository

Tags: apt

I have local repository of xenial in `/CDs/ubuntu` directory. My sources.list file:

```
deb file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

Results of update:

```
#apt-get update
Get:1 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:1 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial Release [246 kB]
Get:2 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial Release [246 kB]
Get:3 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:3 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:4 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:5 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Get:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:9 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:9 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:10 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:11 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:11 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Get:12 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:13 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:13 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Get:14 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:14 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Get:15 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:15 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Get:16 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:17 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:18 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:18 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Get:19 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:20 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:20 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Get:21 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:22 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:22 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:4 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Ign:4 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Get:5 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,196 kB]
Ign:5 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Get:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Ign:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [733 kB]
Ign:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]
Ign:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:9 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Ign:9 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:10 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8,684 B]
Ign:10 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:11 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Ign:11 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Get:12 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 B]
Ign:12 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:13 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Ign:13 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Get:14 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7,512 kB]
Ign:14 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Get:15 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Ign:15 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Get:16 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,410 kB]
Ign:16 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:17 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]
Ign:17 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:18 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Ign:18 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Get:19 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]
Ign:19 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:20 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]
Ign:20 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Get:21 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63.8 kB]
Ign:21 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:22 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [230 kB]
Ign:22 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:4 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,558 kB]
Get:5 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1,552 kB]
Get:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [799 kB]
Ign:6 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Get:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,189 kB]
Err:7 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File not found - /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml (2: No such file or directory)
Get:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [481 kB]
Err:8 file:/CDs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  File not found - /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar (2: No such file or directory)
Reading package lists... Done                 
E: Failed to fetch file:/CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  File not found - /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch file:/CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  File not found - /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar (2: No such file or directory)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

In `/var/lib/apt/lists`, I have nothing. Only partial info in `partial` directory:

```
#/var/lib/apt/lists/partial# ls -l
total 7308
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7228243 Apr 22 09:37 _CDs_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      54 May 13 10:25 _CDs_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz -> /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      53 May 13 10:25 _CDs_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages.gz -> /CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  245864 Apr 22 11:24 _CDs_ubuntu_dists_xenial_Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     933 Apr 22 11:24 _CDs_ubuntu_dists_xenial_Release.gpg
```

The problem can be solved only by downgrade to apt 1.1 from `trusty`.

Additionally new `apt-get update` tries to change the rights of files that it stores as symbolic links in `/var/lib/apt/list`. For example it changes the access rights of file:

```
/CDs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

Any suggestions how to use apt 1.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 with local repo?

Answer (score 6):

for use with apt 1.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 with local repository you need remove this file:

> `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`

using:

> `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works better :) .  apt 1.2 loads files but leaves them in directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial.

Comment: @henry_sosa I continued with the same error after your sugestion

Comment: So if the problem is `50appstream` trying to get stuff like icon files and failing, is there a way to fix that by putting the needed files in the mirror?  I am trying to keep the mirror on a portable drive.  When I take it to a new machine, adding new lines to `/etc/apt/sources/list` is a natural step to take on the target machine.  Deleting `50appstream` not so much

Comment: So I've thought a bit more.  The Ubuntu version of `apt-mirror` was updated to mirror the dep11 files not long ago.  My problem is that the network connected machine I fetch the mirror with was actually a Debian Jessie based machine, and it probably does not have that feature.  I've copied the Ubuntu `apt-mirror` script onto the drive where my repository is, and will use that to update my mirror when I get back to the networked machine

Comment: I do not have this file on Ubuntu 16 yet I still experience the same symptoms. Are there any other things you would suggest checking?

Answer (score 1):

For me, alone deleting

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

didn't work, because I had downloaded *only* the `amd64` packages. To get it to work, I had add the architecture to the `sources.list` lines

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:/wherever xenial main restricted universe multiverse
...etc.
```

After doing this `apt-get update` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried to fix this problem

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

But it didn't work for me. I red about a possible bug abut it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/1550852)

In any case I find an alternative and works very well for me

I open the directory where I have my repository and execute the fallowing command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer <port>
```

is a easy way to start a webserver in any folder you can see this in [How to easily start a webserver in any folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377389/how-to-easily-start-a-webserver-in-any-folder)

So now you can use you sources.list like when you use repository by http. For example in my case I use the por 8585 and this is my sources.list

```
deb http://localhost:8585/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://localhost:8585/ xenial-backports main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://localhost:8585/ xenial-proposed main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://localhost:8585/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://localhost:8585/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

Is quick solution, I'm pretty sure that there another solutions in this way more strong.