# Unable to download packages from local cosmic repository

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, localrepository

Tried making a local copy of the cosmic repo, but every time I try installing a package I'm getting `Package has no installation candiate`.

I followed the steps [here](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Set_up_a_local_Ubuntu_debian_apt_mirror.html) to create the local repo.

This is my mirror.list

```
############# config ##################
#
set base_path    /mnt/mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I made the symlink in /var/www/html to point to the repo for apache2:

```
ls -la /var/www/html/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan  1 11:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan  1 11:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10918 Jan  1 11:32 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    44 Jan  1 11:58 ubuntu -> /mnt/mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I updated my sources.list and ran apt-get update

```
deb http://127.0.1.1/ubuntu cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://127.0.1.1/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://127.0.1.1/ubuntu cosmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

I can see the directories when I visit the page in a browser, and it looks like it matches the official repo.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853632/ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-update-fails-with-local-repository) where he used the following:

```
deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] file:///home/discoprodigy debbin/
```

Modified my sources.list:

```
deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://127.0.0.1/ubuntu cosmic main restricted universe multiverse
```

Looks like adding architecture and trusted fixed the problem.